# How could I hold free electrons in a container?

Tags: electrons, vacuum

I want to hold a small number of free electrons in a container indefinitely.  I read about electron "bottles" and I am curious how I could replicate this. How low of a vacuum would I need to prevent the electrons from being bound in ions? Also,  how much electricity in amps and volts would I need to send down the vacuum tube? Lastly, could I seal the conducting ends of the tube off with hot glue or some other insulator to prevent the electrons from leaving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gabrielse and collaborators](http://gabrielse.physics.harvard.edu/) kept a single electron in a [Penning trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap) for more than a year --- I understand they threw it a birthday party. There are many technical papers, [some of which have reached a wide audience](https://www.wimp.com/jim-carrey-and-conan-obrien-have-a-conversation-about-quantum-physics/).

Comment: This feels right at the boundary between a link-only answer that would do better as a comment and an answer that ought to stand on its own. So, here it is. Vote.

Comment: where could I buy a penning trap?

Comment: @baconcat I wouldn't expect that to be an off-the-shelf commercial item --- there are too many different things one might want to do with it which would require customization. I encourage you to follow the links and get into the literature.